# Const function's parameters: should it be passed by reference or not?

Tags: c++, performance, pass-by-reference

I went to interview for a program job recently and they asked me to write some function that would take a vector and a integer as parameters. The task was to count the number of elements in the vector that were above, below or equal to the integer. I wrote something along these lines:

```
void printStat(const std::vector<int> &vec, const int &val)
{
    int results[3] = {0,0,0};
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        int option = (vec[i] == val) ? 0 : ((vec[i] > val) ? 1 : 2);
        results[option]++;
    }
    ...
}
```

They made a couple of remarks about the code which I found dubious and I'd like to know the opinion of C++ experts. They said that passing `vec` and `val` by reference was less efficient than by value. That it would have been better to write:

```
void printStat(const std::vector<int> vec, const int val) {}
```

To be honest, I have always written my code using the first version (at the top) and didn't really have the argument to explain why my method would be better or no different than theirs. Their argument was that passing the argument by reference forces later one to dereference the variable when you want its content, which is slower than if I had passed the variable by value.

So my question is: what's the best way, and what would be the reason?

Bonus Question: they also argued that using an iterator in the loop would have been more efficient than using the `[]` operator to access the element of the vector. I don't see any reason for this, particularly as I suspect that `vec[i]` will be in the L1 cache when accessed twice in line 5.

Thank you.

Comment: Oh wow, what a load of bollocks. Clearly they care too much about "efficiency" (and they seem to have some nebulous definition of it) and completely disregard semantics. I wouldn't take the job.

Comment: there's no benefit in passing a `const int&`, but plenty in passing a reference to the `std::vector`.

Comment: Yes I would agree with `int&` but is there a penalty of doing so compared to writing `const int val`?

Comment: @user18490 yes, there could be a penalty - per Joachim's answer you might end up (effectively) passing a 64 bit pointer instead of a single 32 bit value.  It wouldn't be a significant penalty, though.

Comment: @user18490: Yes, passing by reference will (almost certainly) require an extra level of indirection to access the object. The compiler may or may not be able to optimise that out; if you pass by value, it won't have to. For a large or complex object like `vector`, the cost of copying is probably more than the cost of indirection, so you should probably pass that by reference.

Comment: "Bonus Question: they also argued that using an iterator in the loop would have been more efficient than using the [] operator to access the element of the vector." IIRC some versions of MSVC were not as happy with `[]` as with iterators. Iterators typically can be optimized to pointers, so you only need to increment and dereference them. Semantically, `[]` implies adding an integer to a pointer. This gets worse if the element access is more complicated, e.g. for matrix classes.

Comment: @DyP adding an integer to a pointer is a fundamental operation in any assembler instruction set, and on a modern CPU should require no additional cycles.

Comment: @DyP and Mike Seymour: very good answers, thank you so much. I have to think though that in my case, the cost of building an iterator for such a simple process and the fact that the content of vec[i] is likely to be held in the L1 cache, make my choice good in this particular case. But that's my opinion and I am not sure about the L1 cache thing.

Comment: @Alnitak: so you are suggesting that using [] is not more costly than using an iterator? I guess at least with the explanation that adding of integer to a pointer doesn't require additional cycles?

Comment: @user18490 I will not claim this still holds for current versions of MSVC; and IIRC the test showed no difference between `[]` and iterators on gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you will use `vec`. If you're not having a lot of entries in the vector it's okay to pass it by value as the copying will be pretty quick. But generally it's more "effective" to pass it by reference.

The `val` argument on the other hand, for native types there is generally no need to pass them as constant references. Actually, as references are often (if not always?) implemented as pointers under the hood, passing this parameter as a reference will on a 64-bit machine pass a 64-bit value compared to a 32-bit value for plain `int`. And as this is a pointer, it will use extra indirection as well.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. They are good and clear. Good point about the pointer on a 64 bits machine taking up more than the value itself.

Comment: @user18490 About the size of `int` versus a pointer (reference), that's not the big issue as noted by others, it's the extra indirection.

Comment: good thank you. This is true, in general, but in this particular case, once the indirection has been made to access the content of val, I would assume val will exist in the L1 cache. Does accessing it the second time requires another indirection. Passing the variable by value will cause an copy operation which has a cost on its own?

Answer (score 1):

Passing objects of built-in types by ref causes extra load. Just use const int val, if you want prevent it from modifications. Using std::vector by ref seems absolutely performant.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick to pass objects by const reference. An exception is, if a copy is made anyway (a const T makes no sense, besides preventing an accidental change in a function implementation).

However: I changed the way to implement `operator =`.

```
T& operator=(const T& other) {
   T(other).swap(*this);
   return *this;
}
```

to

```
T& operator=(T other) {
   other.swap(*this);
   return *this;
}
```

to allow copy elision and move semantics.

Comment: Did you forget the `=` after the `operator` keyword?

Comment: (meanwhile this is fixed)